# Access Denied You don't have permission to access "site" on this server using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've been using selenium with chrome and I've been trying to access a website but I keep receiving this error message:

Access Denied You don't have permission to access "website" on this server.

The website works fine on my regular chrome browser, but when opened through selenium I receive this error message.

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'CHL130688', ip: '10.100.40.93', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?

Comment: Webs can detect robotic access and block it. Ask webmaster if webcrawlers are allowed.